# phpmailer sending success but not delivered

Tags: phpmailer

My PHP mailer is not working on my pc but working on friends.. here is the code of mailer. I tried in Kali Linux it's working but not sending delivering emails... my friend has windows pc and I am also using it on windows using xampp... I set up environment variable c:\xampp\php etc...

```
    <?php

    //Regards
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $date = date('F d, Y, h:i A T');

    /* W3LL SMTP SETUP */
    $smtp_acc = [
[
            "host"     => "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
    "port"     => "587",
    "username" => "email@s.com",
    "password" => "smtppass"
],
[
    "host"     => "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
    "port"     => "587",
    "username" => "email@s.com",
    "password" => "smtppass"
],
[
    "host"     => "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
    "port"     => "587",
    "username" => "email@s.com",
    "password" => "smtppass"
],

];

    /* W3LL Features SETUP */

 $W3LL_setup = [
"priority"       => 1,
"userandom"      => 0,
"sleeptime"      => 1,
"replacement"    => 1,
"filesend"       => 1,
"userremoveline" => 0,
"mail_list"      => "file/maillist/tester.txt",
"fromname"       => "from",
"frommail"       => "support@domain.com",
"subject"        => "sunject",
"msgfile"        => "file/html/1.html",
"filepdf"        => "",
"links"          => [""],
];
```

Comment: can we see the full code?

Comment: There isn't a sufficient config info, but at this point, what you are missing: did you attempt to connect to your PC's mail server by hand, like telnet?

Comment: well the problem got solved when i disabled antivirus core shields... now its sending.... but not delivering.. neither in inbox and spam... i am using html templete as message....

Comment: I used my friends PC to send via my gsuite smtp.. it's working... Delivering inbox... But not on my pc.. even though i setup the friends PC for sender.. and mine.. all settings are same.. when I am using his sender on my pc still not delivering.. please help..